# I have this in Twig and the variable spits out all the debug code rather just a link, What do I do?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

Here is the twig variable being set

```
{% set link = content.field_external_quote_link %}
```

When I just display the variable, it is coming out wrong.

For example if I do this in the HTML below:

```
<a href="{{ link }}" class="button button--primary no-external-link">TEXT EXAMPLE</a>
```

It is dumping out devel code and other things I don't want. Is there something I need to do with the original variable set to get it to just dump the url in plain text?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223488/how-to-stop-twig-debug-from-breaking-html-when-inside-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ link.0.url }}
```

or

```
{{ link[0].url }}
```

or

You can make `{{ link }}` work, if you change your field settings within the node type display setting page, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Goto your content type settings.
Goto: Manage Display
For the desired field, change format to display value as plain text or URL only.
WHich will tell drupal not to render it.

Now, clear cache. And, check again. It should work.